# Objeto enviado pelo Android chegando Null no servidor WebService

Tags: android, web-service, eclipse, glassfish

Estou criando um APP Android para trabalho da faculdade, estou utilizando Android Studio e Eclipse Mars com Glassfish 4.

O webservice acredito estar okay, pois realizando as solicitações pelo SoapUI tudo funciona certinho, porém na hora de consumir com o Android Studio, o objeto que chega no servidor é Null.

Segue o código utilizado para o Android chamada no Android Studio:

```
        public boolean inserirUsuario(Cliente cliente){

        SoapObject inserirUsuario = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, INSERIR);

        SoapObject user = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "cliente");

        user.addProperty("id", cliente.getId());
        user.addProperty("cpf", cliente.getCpf());
        user.addProperty("primeiroNome", cliente.getPrimeiroNome());
        user.addProperty("sobrenome", cliente.getSobrenome());
        user.addProperty("email", cliente.getEmail());
        user.addProperty("senha", cliente.getSenha());
        user.addProperty("ddd", cliente.getDdd());
        user.addProperty("telefone", cliente.getTelefone());
        user.addProperty("ativo", cliente.isAtivo());

        inserirUsuario.addSoapObject(user);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(inserirUsuario);

        envelope.implicitTypes = true;

        HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            http.call("\"urn:inserirUsuario\"", envelope);

            SoapPrimitive resposta = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            return Boolean.parseBoolean(resposta.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Já tentei tirar o "user" e mandar somente o "inserirUsuario", porém de ambas manerias os objetos estão chegando Null no servidor.

Alguém já teve um problema semelhante e pode me ajudar com a solução?

Answer (score 0):

nunca usei soap no android. Mas aconselho a dar uma vista de olhos em http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/tips.html

activa o log debug no httptransport e ve o que esta a sair. Desta forma pode ser que consigas detectar o problema.

happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma requisição para o seu webservice utilizando o postman e veja se o objeto vai chegar nulo. Caso chegue você saberá que o problema não está a principio no android.

Tente também imprimir o objeto que está sendo enviado para ver se o mesmo já não está vazio no inicio do envio.