# Objeto ksoap chega vazio no servidor

Tags: android

Meu problema é semelhante [a outra pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120046/objeto-enviado-pelo-android-chegando-null-no-servidor-webservice), mas que não teve uma resposta marcada como correta, apenas sugestões de inspeção.

Estou trabalhando em um projeto baseado em webservice. Tudo esta funcionando mas não estou conseguindo fazer a comunicação entre o cliente e o servidor apenas para os métodos de inclusão e alteração de uma tabela específica (atleta). Minha inspeção diz que o objeto sai com valores, mas chega no WS vazio.
Se alguém puder me dar alguma orientação, antecipadamente agradecido.

[image: PrintScreen debug HttpTransportSE]

[image: Objeto recebido no servidor. Null]

Comment: Toda vez que alguém chama o Stack Overflow de fórum, Deus mata um gatinho. Por favor, tenha pena dos gatinhos.

Comment: Seria útil indicar a qual pergunta de um ano e meio atrás você se refere.

Comment: Não estou acostumado, por isto as falhas. segue abaixo, de 26/03/2016 web service - Objeto enviado pelo Android chegando Null no servidor ...

Comment: Você pode postar o xml que está sendo enviado para o webservice?

Comment: Rodrigo, estou usando ksoap2, que trabalha com List<>, talvez um pouco semelhante a Json ou xml não sei, Não domino este assunto como gostaria. Segue abaixo o objeto , extraido do debug BodyOut, mas chega  vazio, só nesta tabela.atletaAlterar{atleta
{id=247;
 nome=YURI LIPATIN CHIESA alterado;
 sexo=M;
 CBDA=300764;
 dtNascimento=2004-12-29;
 telefone=; RG=12.442.103-9;
 CPF=;
 email=yurichiesa@gmail.com;
 nomePai=Sergio;
 nomeMae=Silvia;
 clubeId=1;
 tituloClube=C 3957-2;
 colegio=18;
 tecnico=2;
 dtRegistro=12042017;
 status=1;
 pesquisa=yuri lipatin chiesa alterado; }}